# How do you get calculations when you reverse the the values of a scale?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I created a questionnaire with values of 1 (very easy) to 5 (very difficult) and did the calculations of the average based on the results.

However, now my client wants the values to be 5 (very easy) to 1 (very difficult). How could I do the calculation of the average now (using the average values established in the original scale)?

for example if 1.9 was very easy what would the reverse value be?

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse value"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer should be $6-1.9 = 4.1$. The reason is that for any given answer $a$ where $1\leq a\leq 5$, you want to switch it $5-a +1 = 6-a$ (the +1 is to ensure your scale is still between 1 and 5 instead of 0 to 4) so as to make 5 very easy and 1 very difficult.

The average works in the same way. The average is computed by $A=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^na_j$ which then changes to 
$$A' = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n 6-a_j = \frac{6n - \sum_{j=1}^na_j}{n} = 6 - A$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is a value on the original scale, the corresponding $y$ on the reversed scale is given by $y=f(x)= 6-x$. The new average would be $f(1.9)=6-1.9=\boxed{4.1}$.